# How do I save data, that would normally be in a database, to a SharePoint folder or the site's root folder

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a project for my employer that is off-job-description for me. I am not in my department's IT/WebDev departments. That being said, my department is trying to streamline a process that is horribly done right now. Here's what I'm trying to do..

I want a form that can be submitted on a local computer (no `PHP` library at this time - ticket opened with IT for months now). It will then be used to populate a calendar (which I have no issue programming and filling automatically with `PHP` normally, but like I said - no library).

Basically - I need to be able to save the input data locally on a `SharePoint` folder and be able to "grab" that data when the `site` is loaded.

Again, I have no problem with the display/structure parts - I just need to know a good way to save/load the data (long term) until my IT gets its... stuff... together and get's me a `php` library and `SQL Database`.

> I'm not looking for any type of script help or anything. I can learn what I need. I just need ideas of what type of `function` or **something** I can use. If you have a website with some tutorials or at least documentation for it, I'm happy to read up myself.

Comment: I think you're saying that you don't want to use a server at the moment, correct?

Comment: Yes - My company has yet to give me access to a Server or Database or PHP Library

Comment: In which case you are not going to be able to go from the browser to Sharepoint directly. Browsers are locked down from doing this sort of thing. Without that, browsers would be a security risk.

Comment: What is stopping you installing PHP on a spare PC, or your own PC for the time being?

Comment: understandable - what about browser to a local folder? There's only 2 people that use it. In regards to it being on my PC - that's not an issue at all, but the other co-worker wouldn't be able to access it.

Comment: No, browsers cannot write to a local file for the same security concerns as I mentioned.

Comment: You would be able to open up the port to your local PHP (firewall) so that other users could access your PHP. This would only work if they were on the same network.

Comment: Well darn. I'll just work on a PHP version for now until my IT is able to get the two of us connected with a `SQL Database` and `PHP Library`. I do appreciate your help though.

Comment: No problem. I can put the above into an answer if you like. You've lost your bounty points anyway ;-)

Comment: You might as well take them :)

Comment: If it's only two people, you could look at using SQLite if you want something lightweight. Many moons ago I built something that was backed by a Sharepoint list. Not sure if that opens any ideas for you. There is also forms for Sharepoint (I know you said no servers, but you are already using Sharepoint, so..). Thirdly, there is also the WebDav protocol which you could consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers cannot access your local filesystem and are heavily sandboxed to protect you and your data from nefarious websites (even if you have written them).

As such, your only option of writing data to a Sharepoint folder is to leverage a server of some kind. This can be created locally on your own PC, or on a spare one for the time being.

You might to need to contact your IT admin, so that they can grant you access to your Sharepoint, so that your PHP code can read/write to your Sharepoint folder(s).

Good luck!

Comment: I have to wait until tomorrow to reward - I'll check back then